# TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the script used in [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LeZN0Q4rHl68LmYV3yA4ErFJDggXFwMRoQmFpJmepJY/edit#gid=0)
The goal is to split a cell with data split by "," in to multiple rows maintaining the data from corresponding columns in the row.

I keep getting the following error when I run the script:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")

```
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ", "
  targetColumn = 1

  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == targetColumn) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

Comment: `kLen=range[0].length` is not the correct way to right.

Comment: Where is ``range`` defined?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not a coder.  I copied this script from another post and didn't get a response from the original poster.  I believe the range would be defined in the actual sheet where I would use =result(range).  This worked for the original poster but it was an old post.  I'm guessing there has been some change with sheets scripts since then.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this is the sort of thing you are trying to accomplish so perhaps this simple example will help.  The function looks at column 4 and splits the comma separated values up into array tA and then creates a separate line for each value with the same values in the other columns.

Here's my data before running:

[image]

Here's my data after running:

[image]

and Here's my code:

```
function splitDataIntoSeparateRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var tA=vA[i][3].split(',');
    if(tA.length>1){
      for(var j=0;j<tA.length;j++){
        var vB=[vA[i][0],vA[i][1],vA[i][2],tA[j]];
        if(j==0){
          vA.splice(i + j,1,vB);
        }else{
          vA.splice(i + j,0,vB);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

You'll probably need to take a look at the documentation to see how the function works for yourself.

Comment: I found out that even though the original script gives an error when I run it in the script editor it works as intended when saved and used in sheet.  didn't realize that was possible. anyway all is well. Thanks though!